# Make Server Stream Videos Faster

Tags: node.js, streaming, video-streaming, server-side, http-streaming

I have a video on demand platform hosted in a server with 1GB Bandwidth / 11GB RAM / 4 CPU Cores.

I'm reaching now 10.000 users/day and the stream start being slow.
I'm using nodeJS on server-side with [send module](https://github.com/pillarjs/send) for streaming.

I want to provide the best streaming experience for my users, so what I need to do to make the stream faster.

Comment: Use a CDN .....

Comment: Can you help me with more informations or a link for a good article I can start with

Comment: Yes. I would recommend typing CDN into google.

Comment: Price Estimation 16k$/month, I can't afford that ><

Comment: @YahiaMgarrech just a passing suggestion... Did you consider using video hosting sites like Google Video? Upload a test file(s) to their server and see how it handles x-amount connections without slowing down (your site player is middle-man between user and video file at Google server).